# nhibernate queryover.where error

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, lambda, compiler-errors

I recently started playing withe nhibernate and am currently trying to implement a generic function that search the database for entries with a specific name:

```
    public T FindName<T>(string name) where T : class
    {
        T obj;
        using (ISession session = m_SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            obj = session.QueryOver<T>()
                .Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

The problem is that I get a complaint for the ".Where(x => x.Name == name)" statement: "Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 1 arguments". From what I saw on the web, this statement is used quite often and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to ensure that you can call Name on x of type T.

This can be achieved by making an interface with a property Name, type string, and specifying...

where T : class, INameable

Here's some code:

```
interface INameable
{
   string Name { get; }
}

class MyClass
{
  ISessionFactory m_SessionFactory;

  public T FindName<T>(string name) where T : class, INameable
  {
     T obj;
     using (ISession session = m_SessionFactory.OpenSession())
     {
        obj = session.QueryOver<T>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
     }
     return obj;
  }
```

Comment: @Morris: I feel this is the case of a bad compiler error message.  It should give better guidance in such a simple case.  The fact that it's a generic of a generic does make things slightly complicated for the compiler though.